# Scrolling circle bars on the right side?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a scrolling circles that navigates each section of my page like this: http://goo.gl/kAhj8J

However for some reason I don't how to start it with jQuery.

Here's my Markup:

```
<section class="background-fixed img-1" >
        <div class="main-content">
            <h2>Title here</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem dolor beatae, laudantium eos fugiat, deserunt delectus quibusdam quae placeat, tempora ea? Nulla ducimus, magnam sunt repellendus modi, ad ipsam est.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="background-fixed img-2">
        <div class="main-content">
            <h2>Title here</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem dolor beatae, laudantium eos fugiat, deserunt delectus quibusdam quae placeat, tempora ea? Nulla ducimus, magnam sunt repellendus modi, ad ipsam est.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="background-fixed img-3">
        <div class="main-content">
            <h2>Title here</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem dolor beatae, laudantium eos fugiat, deserunt delectus quibusdam quae placeat, tempora ea? Nulla ducimus, magnam sunt repellendus modi, ad ipsam est.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="background-fixed img-4">
        <div class="main-content">
            <h2>Title here</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem dolor beatae, laudantium eos fugiat, deserunt delectus quibusdam quae placeat, tempora ea? Nulla ducimus, magnam sunt repellendus modi, ad ipsam est.</p>
        </div>
```

Here's the JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/prjo2ggv/1/

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are planning to use full page sections you could use [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) for it with the option `navigatio:true` as [in this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/navigationV.html).
Then you can style the navigation as you wish with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, create your circles with a fixed position. On your IMG / DIV tag, add a class "scroll" to it. Then add the Jquery library and script to the HEAD section of your script.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
           jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
                });
            });
</script> 
</head>
<body>
//your circle 
<a href="example.com/index.php#page2" class="scroll">link</a>

//the place you want to scroll to
<div id="page2">
//your info
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any demo for this mate?

Comment: the DIV ID works as an anchor. Meaning when you do a link with #page2 it will auto jump to that location. Jquery is used to change the jump to a scroll. Cheers